# Excel 365 - crash on instruction Workbooks.Open

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

Since a couple of days, I have a crash on the instruction Workbooks.Open with Excel 365. This instruction is part of a macro I developed to open excel file, checking first if the file exist or is already open and then calling the Workbooks.Open instruction.

The specific code is the following:

```
On Error Resume Next
   Workbooks.Open FileName:=Full_File_Name, Updatelinks:=0   -> excel 365 exit here 
                                                             -> no errors despite the On Error Resume Next 

   errnum = Err
        
   Select Case errnum
       Case 0
            ' Ok continue
       Case 40040
            'Ignore this error - continue
       Case Else
            MsgBox ("Check pathname and file name of your file" & File_Name)
       End Select
```

The same code works also perfectly on Excel 2016

I changed the syntax of the line:

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=Full_File_Name, Updatelinks:=0
```

to

```
set wb = Workbooks.Open (FileName:=Full_File_Name, Updatelinks:=0)
```

and declared at the top the function:
Dim wb As Workbook

With this new syntax there is no crash but now at the end of the exit of some macros calling this function, the macro is reaching its end but Excel freezes:

- behavior on an HP 15 laptop Windows 11 - 16gb (bought in 2021): in the menu Files entries like close are greyed and the only way to exit from Excel is to click on the red cross at the top right of the Excel window and close excel thus generating a report to Microsoft.
- behavior on an HP DV7 laptop Windows 10 - 8gb (bought in 2010): none of the menu entries are responsive and the only way to exit is to click on the red cross at the top right of the Excel window and close excel thus generating a report to Microsoft.

The whole function code is the following:

```
Function OpenFileIfClosed(FilePathName As String, FileName As String)

'open a closed excel file, let it open if already open

' reply code:
' returns  1 (constant FileisOpen = 1 in the definitions) if the File is open
' or retunrs the VBA error code

    
    Dim errnum As Variant
    Dim rc As Boolean
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Dim Full_File_Name As String
        
        
    Full_File_Name = FilePathName & "\" & FileName
    
    'Call function to check if the file is open
    rc = IsFileOpen(FileName)
    
    Debug.Print ("IsFileOpen reply = " & rc)
    
    If rc Then
        Debug.Print ("Already open")
        OpenFileIfClosed = 1 'rc = 0 means no errors, therefore file closed -> open the file
    Else
    
        On Error Resume Next
        'Workbooks.Open FileName:=Full_File_Name, Updatelinks:=0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Full_File_Name, Updatelinks:=0)
        errnum = Err
        Select Case errnum
            Case 0
                ' OK continue
            Case 40040
                'Ignore this error - continue
            Case Else
                MsgBox ("Check Path name and File Name of your file" & FileName)
        End Select
           
        
        rc = IsFileOpen(FileName)
        Debug.Print ("IsFileOpen reply = " & rc)
        If rc Then
            OpenFileIfClosed = 1
        Else
            ' erreur à l'ouverture du fichier
            OpenFileIfClosed = Err
        End If
    End If
 
End Function


Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim IsWorkBookOpen As Variant
    Dim xWb As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(FileName)
    IsFileOpen = (Not xWb Is Nothing)
    
    'disable "On Error" (en principe automatique)
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

I would like to know:

- why the syntax Workbooks.Open FileName:=Full_File_Name, Updatelinks:=0 is not working anymore but still working on Excel 2016
- is there a way to analyze why Excel freezes (not sure it has a link with the new syntax?)

Comment: How exactly are you calling the long function from another procedure?

Comment: If this is a matter of Excel versions, it might be a bug introduced by a recent update. It wouldn't be the first time. Does it do that for all the files that you try to open or only some of them?

Comment: What is the bitness of the two machines?

Comment: How exactly are you calling the long function from another procedure?                
                                                                                                                                  
 Dim rc As Variant                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                      
rc = OpenFileIfClosed(Pub_Str_Path_File_Export, Pub_Str_File_Name_Hiboutik_Export_Benefs & ".csv")

Comment: The Excel freezes and the Excel crash on Workbooks.open(....) are not linked. 
I made another change in my code a few days before I discovered the crash on Workbooks.OpenThis change was related to the display of temporary message using a userform with vbModeless and the use of Application.ScreenUpdating = True and False

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    UserForm1_Message.Show vbModeless
    Sleep (Timer_Milleseconds)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    I will open a separate request for this issue.

Comment: What is the bitness of the two machines?
The two machines are 64 bits

Comment: How do you continue in the calling procedure i.e. how do you set the workbook, worksheet, ranges...?

Comment: Subsequent calls afer a Workbooks.open using my routine are always with the following syntax:
Close a Workbook:
Workbooks(<File Name with its extension>).Close SaveChanges:=True (or False)
Activate a worksheet
Workbooks(<File Name with its extension>).Worksheets(<Worksheet Name>Name_Feuille_Encaissement).Activate
To address a cell :  (example)
Dim Zone_Cell As Range
..
Set Zone_Cell = Range("B2") 'here I address a column containing user names
username  = Zone_Cell.Range("A" & i).Value 'example

I ALWAYS use  'Option Explicit in each modules of my macros (I am a former C programmer)